# Why modification not taking

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here i'm Using Sql Server And i create two tables Like
Cutst

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AuditTab](
    [LastUpdate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
Id    CustName
1     John
```

AuditTab

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblCust](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
LastUpdate  (Datetime)--
//Here its takes date
```

I wrote simple trigger function in Cust

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[lmnTrigger]
   ON  [dbo].[TblCust]
   AFTER  INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    Insert into [dbo].[AuditTab]([LastUpdate]) values(GETDATE())

END
```

When I update cust column John-To Joe it is throwing an error

Comment: *"it throughing an Error....."* - and what is in that error text? Should we guess it?

Comment: The Data Row Was Not Committed?

Comment: Can you provide *exact* and *complete* error text? That one you've posted doesnt' looks like some typical SQL server error message.

Comment: What is the `update` statement you are using?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What is the name of the first table, Cutst or Cust or TblCust, you have 3 versions in the question.

Comment: Works for me, provide update/insert statement int TblCust

Comment: the first table name is cust

Comment: Are you use Sql server 2005? Please read if so: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/925719/bug-you-may-receive-an-error-message-when-you-try-to-use-sql-server-management-studio-to-update-a-row-of-a-table-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: Thank u soo much For your value Information

Comment: @Md gosoddin, did you get anywhere with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Lack of primary key on the table can cause an issue, try to add PK to the table and test it again.

```
ALTER TABLE TblCust
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_TblCust PRIMARY KEY (Id)
```

Other possibility is that data has been truncated, but seems like your columns size is correct.
Is any chance you can provide full error message?